# Load up properties using polymorphism in spring boot

Tags: spring, properties, spring-boot, polymorphism

I am looking to load 3 separate properties for 3 supported country codes (example: us, uk, de) in a spring boot app.

For this, I need to load the appropriate property file for a country code specified in each of the messages that I am trying to process.

Currently, I get the country code info as a string from the message and load the properties file if that country code is present in my HashMap.

`usPropsInfo`, `ukPropsInfo`, `dePropsInfo` are loaded in the configuration class using `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`

```
Map<String, Properties> countryCodeProps = new HashMap<String, Properties>();
countryCodeProps.put ("us", usPropsInfo);
countryCodeProps.put ("uk", ukPropsInfo);
countryCodeProps.put ("de", dePropsInfo);

String countryCode = message.getStringProperty("country");

if(null!=countryCode && countryCode.trim().size()>0
{
    if(countryCodeProps.containsKey(countryCode)){
        Properties props = countryCodeProps.get(countryCode);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this? Can I achieve this using Polymorphism in spring boot?

Thanks,
Abhi

Comment: What do you need it for.

Comment: We need it to map attributes of products that are specific to that country to attributes that are understood by our search and navigation tool for that country.